# Can't delete files in directories I've renamed in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-rename, delete-file

I was messing around with the java.io.File methods today, and stumbled on something kind of weird.

When I rename a directory, I can't seem to ever delete the files or new directory.

```
    File dir = new File("dir");
    dir.mkdir();

    File file = new File(dir, "afile.txt");
    file.createNewFile();

    File newname = new File(dir, "newName.txt");
    file.renameTo(newname);

    File newdir = new File("newdir");
    dir.renameTo(newdir);

    System.out.println("file exists? " + file.exists());
    System.out.println("file deleted? " + file.delete());
    System.out.println("newname exists? " + newname.exists());
    System.out.println("deleted newname? " + newname.delete());
    System.out.println("dir exists? " + dir.exists());
    System.out.println("dir deleted? " + dir.delete());
    System.out.println("newdir exists? " + newdir.exists());
    System.out.println("deleted newdir? " + newdir.delete());
```

Yields the output:

```
    file exists? false
    file deleted? false
    newname exists? false
    deleted newname? false
    dir exists? false
    dir deleted? false
    newdir exists? true
    deleted newdir? false
```

In the filesystem, though, newdir and newname.txt both still exist!

However, if I comment out the renaming of the directory, the delete works fine.

Are there additional rules between delete() and rename() one needs to know about? There's not much in the javadoc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the output:

1. At the end of the renaming, **only** `newdir/` and `newdir/newName.txt` exist. Therefore the first six lines of output should be `false`, and they are. (*In particular, the `newname` variable still refers to `dir/newName.txt`, which no longer exists.*)
2. `newdir` does exist; your output confirms this.
3. The final [`delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) doesn't work because the directory is not empty.

In summary, everything appears to work exactly as one would expect.

Comment: Why can't I delete newName.txt, though?

Comment: @jonnyfive: Because it tries to delete `dir/newName.txt`, and that does not exist anymore (you have renamed it to `newdir/newName.txt`).

Comment: You need to remember two things about instances of java.io.File. 1) They represent a path name not a file 2) They are immutable. This explains why you're observing such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As Aix said in his comment:  it tries to delete `dir/newName.txt`, and that does not exist anymore, since you renamed it to `newdir/newName.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying file channels haven't been closed by the JVM, you will be unable to delete the files from Explorer as they will still be flagged as locked.